# Repeatedly replacing parts of a string in a loop

Tags: python

I created a HTML text cleaner, which deletes data between tags.
It's working fine on one iteration, but not in a loop.

The problem is, I cannot save newhtml as a variable due to Python's string immutability.
So, my loop is only working for the last iteration of the function return.

What would be the best practice in such a situation?

```
def find_all(a_str, sub):
    start = 0
    while True:
        start = a_str.find(sub, start)
        if start == -1: return
        yield start
        start += len(sub) # use start += 1 to find overlapping matches

def replace_string(index1, index2, mainstring):
    replacementstring = ''
    return mainstring.replace(mainstring[index1:index2], replacementstring)

def strip_images(html):
    begin_indexes = list(find_all(html, '<DESCRIPTION>GRAPHIC'))
    end_indexes = list(find_all(html, '</TEXT>'))
        for i in range(len(begin_indexes)):
            if begin_indexes[i] > end_indexes[i]:
                end_indexes.pop(0)
    else:
        if len(begin_indexes) == len(end_indexes):
            break

    for i in range(len(begin_indexes)):
        #code problem is here--
        newhtml = replace_string(begin_indexes[i],end_indexes[i], html)
        if i == len(begin_indexes) - 1:
            return newhtml
            #code only returns one iteration

var = strip_images(html)
print var
```

Comment: You might want to consider using a proper HTML parsing library for finding tags and getting their content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, here's the code snippet. It's not pretty but it's doing the job of removing text between those two tags:

```
def find_all(a_str, sub):
   start = 0
   while True:
    start = a_str.find(sub, start)
    if start == -1: return
    yield start
    start += len(sub) # use start += 1 to find overlapping matches

def strip_images(html):
begin_indexes = list(find_all(html, '<DESCRIPTION>GRAPHIC'))
end_indexes = list(find_all(html, '</TEXT>'))
for i in range(len(begin_indexes)):
    if begin_indexes[i] > end_indexes[i]:
        end_indexes.pop(0)
    else:
        if len(begin_indexes) == len(end_indexes):
            break

newhtml = html
begin_indexes2 = begin_indexes[::-1]
end_indexes2 = end_indexes[::-1]
for i in range(len(begin_indexes2)):
#for i, value in enumerate(begin_indexes,0):
    #end_indexes.reset_index(drop=True)
    newhtml = list(newhtml)
    del newhtml[begin_indexes2[i]:end_indexes2[i]]

    if i == len(begin_indexes2) - 1:
        str1 = ''.join(newhtml)
        return str1
```

Comment: I had to convert the string to a list. Then delete by index, starting with the longest indexes first working backwards. Lastly, convert back into a string. Lists are mutable in Python, so this is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Your current issue is that `html` never changes within the loop. So, your input will always be for the first iteration, regardless of the length of the lists.

The solution here follows these steps

- Assign the string to the original value before the loop
- Edit within the loop, passing in the current content, returning a replaced string
- Return from the function after the loop

```
newhtml = html 
for begin, end in zip(begin_indexes, end_indexes):
    newhtml = replace_string(begin, end, newhtml)
return newhtml
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, unfortunately it didn't do the job.

Comment: Is it closer to what you expected? What *are* you getting? And what *do you* expect?

Comment: Are you even sure your index lists are correct? Or the replace function works as expected?